# How to handle an abuse complaint?

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, udp, abuse

I have just received an abuse complaint from my hosting service:

> [2014-04-04 03:30:23 CET] [Timestamp:1396575024] [11717182.634230]
>   Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=**My IP**
>   DST=128.204.203.251 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=118 ID=6181 DF
>   PROTO=UDP SPT=53 DPT=52117 LEN=50

How should I address this issue?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? And what is the complaint exactly?

Comment: What makes them think this is abuse rather than normal traffic? Is the volume excessive? Do you operate any nameservers? If so, are they recursive? (If you don't have a procedure for handling abuse complaints, you probably shouldn't be running a server that's open to the Internet.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First one has to ask whether the packet actually originated from your host in the first place. Source IP spoofing happens all the time, and without context that log entry says nothing about the authenticity of the source IP.

Next question is if you are running a DNS server on that host. If there is no DNS server on that host, then the packet they logged is most likely spoofed. And then that's what you should explain to the hosting provider.

If you are running a DNS server, then that packet could be real, but that doesn't necessarily mean there is any reason to complain about it. You do have to ask yourself if you actually need to run a DNS server. If you are running a DNS server, that you don't need in the first place, shutting it down would be a good idea, regardless of the complaint.

Now let's for a moment assume you do have a reason to run a DNS server, and that the packet did in fact originate from your DNS server. Does that mean there is something you need to do?

In that case you should think about ensuring your DNS server cannot be abused in amplification attacks. However the above packet does not look like it was part of an amplification attack. In an amplification attack you would expect to see packets at least close to 512 bytes in size or 4KB if your DNS server supports it. The logged packet is only 50 bytes in size, which is tiny in comparison.

If you are running a DNS server, the most likely explanation for the above log entry is actually a misconfiguration of the firewall, which produced the log entry. Most likely there was a real legitimate DNS request going out and a legitimate DNS reply coming back. But the firewall for some reason had lost the connection tracking entry before the reply came back.

Also the wording is hinting that they dropped the packet rather than sending an ICMP error back. ICMP errors is one of the tools, which can be used to detect spoofing attacks and activate countermeasures.

If DNS servers applied all the best countermeasures against amplification attacks, that are technically possible, then blocking unexpected UDP packets without sending ICMP errors back would be like asking to be attacked.

Which parts of my reasoning are relevant to your case depends a bit on the details. But I hope the hosting provider will realize that the complaint is not valid, when they are presented with the right parts of it.

Answer (score 3):

The source IP is you, the source port is 53 (DNS).
Looks like you have a DNS server, which is open for queries from outside.
This can be intended use like to provide DNS for your own subdomains, but it also can be a misconfigured DNS server which can be used for DNS amplification attacks, which then can be used in (D)DOS attacks against other hosts.

So better check if you need a local DNS server at all and if it should be open to queries from outside. If you need the openly accessible server to resolve your own (sub)domains, make at least sure it cannot be used for recursive queries.

For more information have a look at https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA13-088A or http://help.1and1.com/servers-c37684/parallels-plesk-c37703/protect-against-dns-amplification-attacks-a791842.html